# server got irrelevant parameters from client Ext.Ajax.request on IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, post, extjs, parameters

This issue happens on IE 8 and IE 9. Works fine on firefox. The client code is like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: myUrl,
                method: 'POST',
                params:{
                    myParams:myParams
                });
```

The params on client side is always good, but on server side when get the params, it gets some irrelevant stuff.

If I add `disableCachingParam : myString` to `Ext.Ajax.request`, server side takes this `myString` as part of params.  This issue only happens on IE.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Do you also set disableCaching = true

Comment: I think you need show us example of 'wrong data'. Maybe you need try to use success/failure methods?